# How to remove column of given element in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to delete a particular set of element (column) from a matrix. How can I do so?

```
Input: A = [1 2 1; 4 5 4; 7 8 7]     
       B = [1; 4; 7;] or say A(:,1)

Output: A = [2 1; 5 4; 8 7]
```

I tried with the command `setdiff(A,A(:,1))`, but it did not give the expected result.

Comment: if you know the column number then try either `A = A(:,[1:(n-1), (n+1):end])` or else `A(:,n) = []`. The latter is often less efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three approaches can be suggested here.

1) `setdiff` based -

```
A = setdiff(A.',B.','rows').'
```

2) `ismember` based -

```
A = A(:,~ismember(A.',B.','rows'))
```

3) `bsxfun` based -

```
A = A(:,~all(bsxfun(@eq,A,B)))
```

---

Instead of removing all column matches, if you are looking to remove just the first column in `A` that matches with `B`, you have two approaches.

1) `ismember` based -

```
A(:,find(ismember(A.',B.','rows','legacy'),1))=[]
```

2) `bsxfun` based -

```
A(:,find(all(bsxfun(@eq,A,B)),1))=[]
```

Comment: @user2771151 So you want to remove the first match of column only?

Comment: @user2771151 Check out the edited codes if they work for you?

Comment: @user2771151 Or do you have the column indices of `A` that are to be removed?

Comment: @user2771151  If this solution has adequately answered what you were after, please consider accepting it. Since you have been around on Stackoverflow I am assuming you already know how to do it. Also, accepting solutions makes sure that they don't remain in Unanswered section.